# Patterns for passing context through a method chain

Tags: design-patterns

This is a design decision that appears to come up quite a lot: how to pass context *through* a method that doesn't need it to a method that does. Is there a right answer or does it depend on the context.

### Sample code that requires a solution

```
// needs the dependency
function baz(session) {
  session('baz');
}

// doesn't care about the dependency
function bar() {
  baz();
}

// needs the dependency
function foo(session) {
   session('foo')
   bar();
}

// creates the dependency
function start() {
  let session = new Session();
  foo(session);
}
```

---

### Possible solutions

- threadlocal
- global
- context object
- pass the dependency through
- curry baz and pass it into bar with the dependency set as the first arg
- dependency injection

### Examples of where is comes up

#### HTTP request processing

Context objects in the form of request attributes are often used: see expressjs, Java Servlets or .net's owin.

#### Logging

For Java logging folk often use globals / singletons. See the typical log4j / commons logging / java logging patterns.

#### Transactions

Thread locals are often used to keep a transaction or session associated with a chain of method calls to avoid needing to pass them as parameters to all the methods that don't need them.

Comment: Please use a more meaningful example.

Comment: I've added some examples of where it comes up.

Comment: I meant a more meaningful example code.

Answer (score 11):

The only fair answer is that it depends on your programming paradigm's idioms. If you're using OO, it's almost certainly incorrect to pass a dependency from method to method to method. It's a code smell in OO. In fact, that's one of the problems OO solves -- an object *fixes* a context. So in OO, one correct (there are always other ways) approach is to deliver the dependency via contructor or property. A commenter mentions "Dependency Injection" and that's perfectly legit, but it's not strictly necessary. Just provide the dependency so it's available as a member to `foo` and `baz`.

You mention currying, so I'll assume functional programming isn't out of the question. In that case, a philosophical equivalent of object context is closure. Any approach that, once again, fixes the dependency so it's available to dependents works just fine. Currying is one such approach (and it makes you sound smart). Just remember there are other ways to close over a dependency. Some of them are elegant and some of them awful.

Don't forget about [Aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). It seems to have fallen out of favor in the last few years, but its primary goal is solving *exactly* the problem you describe. In fact, the classic Aspect example is logging. In AOP, the dependency is added automatically after other code is written. AOP folks call this "[weaving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_weaver)". Common aspects are woven into the code at the appropriate places. This makes your code easier to think about and is pretty darn cool, but it also adds a new testing burden. You'll need a way to determine your final artifacts are sound. AOP has answers for that as well, so don't feel intimidated.

Comment: Claiming that passing parameters around within OO methods is a code smell is a highly controversial statement. I'd argue the complete opposite: encouraging mixing state and functionality within a class is one of the biggest mistakes made by the OO paradigm and avoiding it by injecting dependencies directly into methods, rather than via a constructor is a sign of a well designed piece of code, whether OO or not.

Comment: @DavidArno I'd suggest using a different paradigm vs. concluding object statefulness is "one of the biggest mistakes make  by the OO paradigm" and then circumventing the paradigm. I have nothing against almost any approach but generally dislike code where the author is fighting their tool. Private state is a distinguishing feature of OO. If you eschew that feature, you lose some of OO's power.

Comment: @DavidArno A class that is all state and no functionality has no mechanism for enforcing invariant relationships in the state.  Such a class is not at all OO.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, to an extent, you have applied reducto ad absudium to my comment, but your point is still well made. Invariance on state is an important part of "moving on from OO" . So avoiding mixing functionality and state has to allow enough functionality in a state object as needed to achieve invariance (encapsulated fields set by the constructor and accessed via getters).

Comment: @ScantRoger, I agree another paradigm can be adopted, namely the functional paradigm. Interestingly, most modern "OO" languages have a growing list of functional features and so it's possible to stick with those languages and adopt the function paradigm, without "fighting the tool".

Comment: @DavidArno The functional features in modern OO languages are a separate paradigm -- a perfectly legitimate paradigm, but still a separate paradigm. That's why all three approaches above may be possible within a single language. What you seem to be arguing is that pure OO is now defunct given functional features. I don't believe that's correct. Both paradigms have their strengths and weaknesses. Sounds like you've been bitten by the functional bug and that's great. Just don't let it cloud your judgement about what's possible with other tools.

Comment: ... Claiming that functional patterns are preferred to OO patterns is highly controversial ;) When I say "fighting the tool", I mean losing the richness or what's possible because of an over-zealous viewpoint. I don't know your background, but if Haskell/F#/whatever got you excited about pure functional programming, maybe try SmallTalk to get you excited about pure OO programming. To be clear, I'm not claiming that OO is better than functional. Not at all. I'm just highlighting that each paradigm tackles the OP's problem in different, yet effective, ways.

Comment: If we are talking alternative paradigms, isn't this one area monads can be used? The compuational context can be precisely captured by eg a Reader or State monad, so we can reason about the dependency as well.

Comment: +1 for saying you have one correct way instead of the correct way

Answer (score 10):

If `bar` is dependent on `baz`, which in turn requires `dependency`, then `bar` requires `dependency` too in order to correctly use `baz`. Therefore, the correct approaches would be to either pass the dependency through as a parameter to `bar`, or curry `baz` and pass that to `bar`.

The first approach is simpler to implement and read, but creates a coupling between `bar` and `baz`. The second approach removes that coupling, but could result in less clear code. Which approach is best will therefore likely depend on the complexity and behaviour of both functions. For example, if `baz` or `dependency` have side effects, ease-of-testing will likely be a large driver in which solution is chosen.

I'd suggest all the other options you propose are both "hacky" in nature and likely to lead to problems both with testing and with difficult to track down bugs.

Comment: I almost agree completely. Dependency Injection may be another Non-"hacky"aproach.

Comment: @JonathanvandeVeen, surely the very act of passing `dependency` around via parameters is dependency injection?

Comment: @DavidArno Dependency injection frameworks don't get rid of these kinds of dependencies, they just move them.  The magic is that they move them outside your classes, to a place where testing is Somebody Else's Problem.

Comment: @JonathanvandeVeen I agree, dependency injection is a valid solution. In fact it's the one I'd most often pick.

Answer (score 1):

**Philosophically Speaking**

I agree with [David Arno's concern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303707/patterns-for-passing-context-through-a-method-chain/303807#comment634603_303715).

I'm reading the OP as looking for implementation solutions. However, the answer is *change the design*. "Patterns"? OO design is, one could say, all about context. It's a vast, blank sheet of paper pregnant with possibilities.

Dealing with existing code is a different, well, context.

---

---

I'm working on 'zactly the same problem right now. Well, I'm fixing the hundreds of lines of code copy-n-paste that was done just so a value can be injected.

**Modularize the code**

I threw away 600 lines of duplicate code then refactored so instead of "A calls B calls C calls D ..." I have "Call A, return, Call B, return, Call C ...".  Now we only need to inject the value into one of those methods, let's say method E.

Add a default parameter to the constructor. Existing callers do not change - "optional" is the operative word here. If an argument is not passed the default value is used. Then only 1 line change to pass the variable into the refactored, modular structure; and a small change in method E to use it.

---

**Closures**

[A Programmers thread - "Why would a program use a closure?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285941/why-would-a-program-use-a-closure)

Essentially, you are injecting values into a method which returns a method customized with the values. That customized method is subsequently executed.

This technique would allow you to modify an existing method without changing its signature.

Comment: This approach looks [oddly familiar](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/274821/22815)...

Comment: Roger on the temporal coupling (your link) issue, @Snowman. It is important that the required execution order is encapsulated.